# Creating a Magento Sitemap page

Tags: magento, sitemap

I want to create a sitemap page for Magento that will display all the static pages in an orderly fashion.  This page is going to be similar to http://www.magentocommerce.com/sitemap/  Has anyone created a Magento Extension or can someone point me in the right direction?  Searching for this feature has been a nightmare since all I get are Google SEO results.

Edit: I would like to add some of the static pages to the site map.  Currently the default sitemap has two options: Categories and Products.  I would like a way to set which of my static pages can be added to the site map.  Right now what I have done is just created a static page which I populated with links to my pages and products.  However, if the client decides to add new products, it would require that page to be edited.

Comment: more information please.  do you want an XML sitemap for search engine submission or other data-oriented work, or an XHTML format for browser consumption?  What's wrong with the default sitemap that you need to change it?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What version of Magento? I believe CMS Pages have been included since 1.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMS > Pages > Manage Hierarchy

Bellow "Add node" button You can set CMS hierarchy with position.

`$collection = Mage::getModel('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node')->load("root_node_id");`

`"root_node_id"` is parent of Your "Sitemap".

Create tree from `$collection`.

Also You can see `enterprise_cms_hierarchy_node` table, you can use columns as atributes from there to position elements inside Your tree.

Comment: I see that this is an enterprise Feature.

Comment: If You want to manage positions etc, then yes.

In magento commerce i think that best solution will be to create new module.

Comment: how to get root_node_id in magento 1.9.2.4